# Is there a way to sort a selection of non blank contiguous cells (i.e. an arbitrarily selected range) using Excel & VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

My Excel document is used as a metal melting document. It is used to mix various alloys. When making a melt, we will select the rows and colour the rows to indicate a selection of material for a melt. I have 5 working buttons which is the limit of melts we would have open at any one time. I also have a sort button and a blank button to remove the colours from the cells once the metal is processed. The blanking button will also delete the data from the highlighted cells.

My problem lies in that I can sort using the Custom Sort functionality of Excel, however, it takes inputs from the user and applies it to the defined range. These inputs are removed when a user selects the next set of ranges.

My sort function is designed to sort by cell colours first in the order yellow, blue, green purple and dark blue, followed by a sort on identity column cell values. Currently, my sort button works on a single column. I want the data across the row to move with the identity column.

All the documents' VBA scripting is in a single module, attached below.

New_macro() - New_macro6() are used for colouring cells and 6 is for colouring None and clearing cells.

**Picture of excel document.**
[image: Picture of excel document.]

ColourSort() is the sorting function which isn't working - **Error is here** -
[image: Enter image here]

I don't want to sort the whole length of the column due to a tallying row at the bottom...

```
Sub New_macro()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection

     Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
 
    End Sub
    Sub New_macro2()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection

     Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
 
    End Sub
    Sub New_macro3()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection

      Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
 
    End Sub
    Sub New_macro4()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection

     Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(122, 48, 160)
 
    End Sub
    Sub New_macro5()

        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection

     Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
 
    End Sub
    Sub New_macro6()

    Dim myRange As Range
         Set myRange = Selection

     Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     Selection.Clear
 
    End Sub
    Sub ColourSort()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

    myRange.Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Selection, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
            192, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Selection, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 176 _
            , 240)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Selection, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(146, _
            208, 80)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Selection, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(122, 48 _
            , 160)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Selection, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 112 _
            , 192)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Selection() _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
                .SetRange Selection
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End Sub
```

Is there a way to exploit the Immediate views ?Selection.Address function?
[image: Selection.Address]

Comment: Are you shure that you use Excel2010?

Comment: It might be excel2016… why do you ask?

Comment: Add2 method is not available in E2010

Comment: Fair enough. I’ll double check the document and if it’s not I’ll revise the tag- thank you for highlighting

Comment: I am running Excel365

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's correct to sort with `SortFields.Add(Selection, ...)`. I think the key for your `SortFields.Add` is supposed to represent a single column by which the data will be sorted.

e.g. this:

```
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Selection() _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

should say something more like

```
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A3:A13") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: I must say, first and for most, “ah ghad”. On a serious note though, you’ve explicitly referenced the cells. If I have a longer data set, then I can’t sort it. It’ll only just sort these cells Range(“A1:A13”). I want the range to reference the cells selected (I.e. shift clicked). I thought about exploiting the string of the select value(I.e string of the cells) , and inserting that into the code as a concatenation, but that didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong.
Initial Macro:

```
Range("A3:C12").Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A3:A12"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    192, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A3:A12"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 176 _
    , 240)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A3:A12"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(146, _
    208, 80)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A3:A12"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(122, 48 _
    , 160)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A3:A12"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, 112 _
    , 192)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A3:A12") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:C12")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
```

As can be seen, the Range at the beginning is "A3:C12". The ranges being used for the sort are only referenced from column A, i.e. "A3:A12". My code will thus work if we replace Selection with myRange.Columns(1), which is what I've done and it works. This makes sense as one only sorts with a single column, and hence requires column 1 only, where my code was trying to sort the rows by all the columns, creating an error.